# How does hibernate fetchmode join work?

Tags: hibernate

I have [one-to-many](/questions/tagged/one-to-many) relationship with `Vendor` to `Customer`. When I perform query using criteria and having `FetchMode.JOIN` I should get one select query but I am getting 8 select queries (1 `Vendor` + 8 `Customer`).

**Code**

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Vendor.class);
criteria.setFetchMode("customer", FetchMode.JOIN);
List<Vendor> listOfVendore = criteria.list();
Iterator<Vendor> veIterator = listOfVendore.iterator();
while (veIterator.hasNext()) {
   Vendor vendor = (Vendor) veIterator.next();
   Set<Customer> listCustomer = vendor.getChildren();
   Iterator<Customer> iterator = listCustomer.iterator();
   while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      Customer customer = (Customer) iterator.next();
   }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hibernate: select this_.vendid as vendid1_1_0_, this_.vendname as vendname2_1_0_ from vendor this_
Hibernate: select children0_.vendid as vendid3_1_1_, children0_.custid as custid1_0_1_, children0_.custid as custid1_0_0_, children0_.custname as custname2_0_0_, children0_.vendid as vendid3_0_0_ from customer children0_ where children0_.vendid=?
Hibernate: select children0_.vendid as vendid3_1_1_, children0_.custid as custid1_0_1_, children0_.custid as custid1_0_0_, children0_.custname as custname2_0_0_, children0_.vendid as vendid3_0_0_ from customer children0_ where children0_.vendid=?
Hibernate: select children0_.vendid as vendid3_1_1_, children0_.custid as custid1_0_1_, children0_.custid as custid1_0_0_, children0_.custname as custname2_0_0_, children0_.vendid as vendid3_0_0_ from customer children0_ where children0_.vendid=?
Hibernate: select children0_.vendid as vendid3_1_1_, children0_.custid as custid1_0_1_, children0_.custid as custid1_0_0_, children0_.custname as custname2_0_0_, children0_.vendid as vendid3_0_0_ from customer children0_ where children0_.vendid=?
Hibernate: select children0_.vendid as vendid3_1_1_, children0_.custid as custid1_0_1_, children0_.custid as custid1_0_0_, children0_.custname as custname2_0_0_, children0_.vendid as vendid3_0_0_ from customer children0_ where children0_.vendid=?
Hibernate: select children0_.vendid as vendid3_1_1_, children0_.custid as custid1_0_1_, children0_.custid as custid1_0_0_, children0_.custname as custname2_0_0_, children0_.vendid as vendid3_0_0_ from customer children0_ where children0_.vendid=?
Hibernate: select children0_.vendid as vendid3_1_1_, children0_.custid as custid1_0_1_, children0_.custid as custid1_0_0_, children0_.custname as custname2_0_0_, children0_.vendid as vendid3_0_0_ from customer children0_ where children0_.vendid=?
```

**Mapping Vendor**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
   "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
   "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="str.Vendor" table="vendor">
      <id name="vendorId" column="vendid">
         <generator class="increment" />
      </id>
      <property name="vendorName" column="vendname" length="10" />
      <set name="children" cascade="all" inverse="true">
         <key column="vendid" />
         <one-to-many class="str.Customer" />
      </set>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Mapping Customer**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
   "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
   "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="str.Customer" table="customer">
      <id name="customerId" column="custid">
         <generator class="increment" />
      </id>
      <property name="customerName" column="custname"
         length="10" />
      <many-to-one name="parentObjets" column="vendid"
         cascade="all" />
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like your member variable in `Vendor` is called `children`, but your query specifies that `FetchMode.JOIN` should be used on something named `customer`. Make sure that the first parameter to `setFetchMode` corresponds to the correct path within `Vendor`.